# Modify SingleResult<T> from TableController in Azure Mobile Services before returning it to the client?

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile Services.  I have a `TableController<Photo>`.  In the controller, I can retrieve a single photo by id successfully.  No problems using the following method:

```
//works   
public SingleResult<Photo> GetPhoto(string id)
{
  return Lookup(id);
}
```

However, since the photo is stored in Azure storage as a private blob, I want to tack on the `SAS (Shared access signature)` to allow my mobile client direct read access to the Azure blob for a given period of time.

In the GetPhoto call, I am successfully retrieving the SAS using the `CloudBlobClient` (removed for brevity).

I have defined a property on Photo called `SasQueryString`.  I want to set it on the <Photo> object retrieved using `Lookup(id)` but the data returned from `Lookup(id)` is an `IQueryable`, not my strongly typed Photo object.

```
//! INCORRECT ! -- because photoResult is IQueryable
public SingleResult<Photo> GetPhoto(string id)
{
  SingleResult<Photo> photoResult = Lookup(id);
  //SingleResult<Photo> does not contain SasQueryString
  photoResult.SasQueryString = "SAS from CloudBlobClient";  
  return photoResult;
}
```

If I do this, I can set the SasQueryString:

```
Photo photoResult = (Photo)Lookup(id).Queryable.FirstOrDefault<Photo>();
photoResult.SasQueryString = "SAS from CloudBlobClient";
```

However, I'm not sure how to return this strongly typed object as a `SingleResult<Photo>`.

```
//! INCORRECT ! -- this doesn't work because the Create method expects an IQueryable
return SingleResult<Photo>.Create(photoResult);
```

I've also tried this but photoResult is an`IQueryable` so I can't set the strongly typed `SasQueryString` value this way either.

```
//! INCORRECT ! 
var photoResult = Lookup(id).Queryable.Select(x => new Photo()
{
    Id = x.Id,
    TheOtherFields = x.TheOtherFields
});    

photoResult.SasQueryString = "SAS from CloudBlobClient";
```

I am obviously missing something crucial here but it seems like I should be able to combine the lookup for the photo and the request for the SAS into a single call that returns my photo data after tacking on the SAS ticket...

== UPDATE ==

I found the following example: [Creating a Leaderboard App with Azure Mobile Services .NET Backend](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-leaderboard/).  It is doing something similar to what I want to do but I have yet to try it.

```
// GET tables/PlayerRank/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
public SingleResult<PlayerRankDto> GetPlayerRank(string id)
{
    var result = Lookup(id).Queryable.Select(x => new PlayerRankDto()
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        PlayerName = x.Player.Name,
        Score = x.Score,
        Rank = x.Rank
    });

    return SingleResult<PlayerRankDto>.Create(result);
}
```

which modified for my situation might look like the following:

```
public SingleResult<Photo> GetPhoto(string id)
{
    var result = Lookup(id).Queryable.Select(x => new Photo()
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        ImageUri = x.ImageUri,
        SasQueryString = GetSas(id),
    });

    return SingleResult<PlayerRankDto>.Create(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing it the right way:

- When you get the a list of Photos or a Photo it will give the data from storage in database and SasQueryString is not storaged, only the Url from blob storage should be;
- You only provide SasQueryString in Insert or Update methods, because you need to define the url or update the url if need;

**Note:** Get methods do not change data

- When a client app insert a photo the backend should do:

  - create the url for the photo and generate the SasQueryString
  - save the photo, with the url create, in database
  - before return the photo set the SasQueryString
  - client app upload the image to blob using the SasQueryString and url you provided

Why you have a Photo and a Controller for Photo???

If you have an object "Car" that has an image, it should have "car.Url" and a class similar to [BlobItem.cs](https://github.com/saramgsilva/AMSToolkit/blob/master/src/AMSToolkit/Blob/BlobItem.cs) and you can see [BlobStorageExtensions.cs](https://github.com/saramgsilva/AMSToolkit/blob/master/src/AMSToolkit/Blob/BlobStorageExtensions.cs).

**Note**: [BlobItem.cs](https://github.com/saramgsilva/AMSToolkit/blob/master/src/AMSToolkit/Blob/BlobItem.cs) will be a not mapped property, I do not want save it on database.

I need to create a sample with it and the nugets...

Comment: I am uploading an image already using code that is quite similar to what you reference in BlobStorageExtension.cs.  However, I want to give a different mobile device that requests the image from the Private blob a read ticket that lasts long enough for them to download the image.  So, in the Get method I want to return a new SAS with Read access.

Comment: Sasquerystring is only available for 5min.... and for that create a custom service that only returns the sasquerystring......

Comment: Yes, I understand -- so that means I need to either figure out a way to modify the data in SingleResult<Photo> -- or somehow convert it to my strongly typed object Photo -- update the value and then convert it back to the SingleResult<Photo> type.  I could create a custom service but then I would have to make an additional call for every photo.